# Backbox Image Viewer not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, image, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I've used the Backbox Image Viewer from http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/ on this website for over 3 years and this problem just arose with the update of IE to version 9.

When you click the link to open the gallery, instead of backbox opening normally, a small all white box appears in it's place. No navigation images or gallery images or anything.

You can view the issue here at http://www.joewheelerknifemaker.com and by clicking on "Knives by Joe, Photo Gallery".

I know that this happens on multiple computers using IE9, but works perfectly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome from what I can tell.

Anyone have any ideas or know what IE changed in this version that could be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btw, i think backbox is much the same as lightbox. There is an solution for lightbox here
http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Thanks! I'll just switch to this lightbox, I like it better... =)